# NodeJS in AWS Lambda to Mongo Atlas - connection fails with no logs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

I am JS newbie so this may be some silly trouble. I have a lambda written in NodeJS 10.x and I am trying to add MongoDB Atlas insertion. I have started with this tutorial: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda/

This is my code:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let cachedDb = null;

function connectToDatabase (uri) {
    console.log('Connect to mongo database');

    if (cachedDb) {
        console.log('Using cached database instance');
        return Promise.resolve(cachedDb);
    }

    return MongoClient.connect(uri)
        .then(db => {
            console.log('Successful connect');
            cachedDb = db;
            return cachedDb;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Connection error occurred: ', err);
            callback(err);
        });
}

function insertUser(db, email) {
    console.log('=> modify database');
    return db.collection('users').insertOne({"email" : email})
        .then(() => { callback(null, result); })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Insert error occurred: ', err);
            callback(err);
        });
}

exports.handler = (payload, context, callback) => {
    const { email, password } = JSON.parse(payload.body);

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    connectToDatabase(MONGODB_URI)
        .then(db  => {
            console.log('Mongo connected')
            insertUser(db, email);
            })
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Mongo insert succeeded', result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Mongo insert failed', err);
            return responses.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_500(err, callback, response);
        });

    console.log('finished mongo stuff');
```

I can see the following logs in CloudWatch:

```
START RequestId: 0338d336-7d33-40d5-abc7-1511f1c9ea4c Version: $LATEST
2020-01-11T12:18:00.808Z    0338d336-7d33-40d5-abc7-1511f1c9ea4c    INFO    Connect to mongo database
2020-01-11T12:18:00.855Z    0338d336-7d33-40d5-abc7-1511f1c9ea4c    INFO    finished mongo stuff
2020-01-11T12:18:01.416Z    0338d336-7d33-40d5-abc7-1511f1c9ea4c    ERROR   (node:8) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
END RequestId: 0338d336-7d33-40d5-abc7-1511f1c9ea4c
```

The item is not inserted in Atlas. I have added more verbose logging but it is not shown. If the mongo connect failed there shall be an error. But it seems that the error handlers are ignored. Where is the problem?

Comment: Note that you have multiple invocations of `callback` (in `connectToDatabase` and `insertUser`) that will all fail because `callback` is undefined.

Comment: should not catch detect it?

Comment: Are you suggesting that this is a deliberate strategy?

Comment: I am not usggesting, but I am asking. I would expect that catch statement shall catch all kinds of errors, shall not it?

Comment: Yes, it will catch a ReferenceError.

Comment: So it should have been traced with console.log('Mongo insert failed', err) but it was not

Comment: Which means that it never attempted to execute that callback and hence never triggered the exception. Your entire Lambda completed, failed, or timed out before it got to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Few things are missing

- callback function needs to be called from your handler function as the insert function doesn't know about callback.
- When you do a `.then` on a promise and you use curly braces you need to return whatever is in there to send it to the next then (unless you do it in a single line).
- db in insert method needs to be db.db()

I would recommend to to use `async/await` instead of callback style. Here is the equivalent code

```
exports.handler = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = JSON.parse(payload.body);

    const db = await connectToDatabase(MONGODB_URI);
    console.log("Mongo connected");
    const result = await insertUser(db, email);
    console.log("Mongo insert succeeded", result);
    return result;
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, I have noticed you changed single quotes to double quotes. Then you removed the quotes from JSON parameter and added then statement in insert method. Error handler in the connect method has callback. Thanks. I deployed the lambda but there is no change. I do not see Succesfull connect log.

Comment: ignore the quotes thins. it is my IDE's linter changing stuff. What are you getting in lambda? are you able to see any console logs? it is giving timeout error? can u paste the response?

Comment: INFO Connect to mongo database
INFO finished mongo stuff

Comment: Neither "Successful connect" nor "Connection error occurred: " is logged. Why?

Comment: have u checked lambda timeout? default is 3 sec

Comment: The method finishes successfuly: Billed Duration: 2800 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 109 MB Init Duration: 671.69 ms

Comment: i guess the latest version of mongo driver you need to do `db.db()` in your `insert` method. try that.

Comment: I think that this method is never called because "Modify database" is never logged. I do not understand why both "Successful connect" and "Connection error occurred: " are missing - at least one shall be logged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205800/discussion-between-ashish-modi-and-leos-literak).

Comment: It seems that it was helpful to remove this statement as well: context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;